# Bash Nested If-Else Error

Tags: bash, unicode, if-statement

I'm trying to get my bash profile to activate a kerl instance on shell startup, so I put the following in my .profile:

```
if [ -d /opt/erlang/ ]; then 
    ERL_ENV=`ls -1d /opt/erlang/r* | sort | tail -1`;

    if [ -f "$ERL_ENV/activate" ]; then
        . $ERL_ENV/activate 
    else
        echo "Couldn't activate latest erlang environment"
    fi
fi
```

When I try to source the file though I get this error:

```
-bash: .profile: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
-bash: .profile: line 30: `    if [ -f "$ERL_ENV/activate" ]; then'
```

I've tried it a few ways but my bash is too rusty.  What's the problem?

I'm using Bash on OSX.(GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12))

Comment: I am not getting any errors for the same piece of code. I am using Fedora 16

Comment: DOS carriage returns in the file?

Comment: Good idea!  This led me to the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to turn on HARD MODE and look at the hex.  Ended up being a unicode character that was copy-pasted in.

The hex for the file looks like this:
[image: Free Hexy Pics!]

The "e2 8082" where the cursor is located in the picture is actually a silly little [En Space](http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U2002/En_Space).
Replacing those with real spaces fixed it.

Thanks for everybody else's answers though!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a problem with line endings, try

```sh
dos2unix .profile
```

[**ref**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)

Comment: Good answer, but wasn't the problem.